# ASP .NET MVC What's going on with my route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a problem, my url is ugly smth like this:

```
http://localhost:43547/Admin?id=1&str=wooh
```

I want see the url like this one

```
http://localhost:43547/LOL
```

My routes are:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "MyRoute",
       "LOL",
       new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", 
             id = UrlParameter.Optional, str = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

routes.MapRoute(
       "Default",
       "{controller}/{action}",
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
       );
```

and I have 2 identical views one of them is with such method

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click me", "Index", "Admin", new { id = 1, str = "wooh" }, null)
```

which moves the page...

and I have 2 controllers:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id = 5485, string str = "Default Value")
{
    ViewBag.ID = id;
    ViewBag.STR = str;
    return View();
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Controller = "Home";
        ViewBag.Action = "Index";
        return View();
    }
}
```

So what's wrong? When I type smth like /LOL
It moves me to another page with default values of id and str...

Comment: What are you trying to do here? From just typing /LOL you should get the default values.  Do you want your route to look something like this: `/LOL/1/wooh`?

Comment: so from your point of view I can't hide default values?

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what your default values are. Are they id=5485 and str="Default Value" or id=1 and str="wooh"?

Comment: ok, look... Default are id=5485 and str="Default Value"... The mission is to hide this ugly URL http://localhost:43547/Admin?id=1&str=wooh to http://localhost:43547/LOL when i'm moving values from 1 view to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `MyRoute` definition to include the id and str parameter values.

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "MyRoute",
       "LOL",
       new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", 
             id = 1, str = "wooh" }
       );
```

That way your url will look like /LOL but will pass the values you need.